# Break Circular Dependency of Two Classes that Depend on Each Other

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, friend, forward-declaration

a part of my program basically boils down to the code below which won't compile due to circular dependency. I know there are previous discussions about this topic, but none of the previous solutions (at least none that I can find) resolves my situation:

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <iostream>

#include "B.h"

class A
{
  public:
    typedef struct a_struct
    {
      int x;
      int y;
    }a_struct_t;

    void print_something() { std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl; }
  
  private:
    typedef struct another_struct
    {
      int x;
      a_struct_t a_struct;
    }another_struct_t;
    
    friend void B::b_func1();
};
    
#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "A.h"

class B
{ 
  public:
    void b_func1();
    A::a_struct_t b_func2();
};

#endif
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

void B::b_func()
{ 
  A::another_struct_t another_struct;
  // Do something with another_struct;
} 

A::a_struct_t B::b_func2()
{
  A::a_struct_t a_struct;
  return a_struct;
}
```

try.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
  A a_object;
  a_object.print_something();

  return 0;
}
```

The issue is `class A` can't friend just `void B::b_func1()` in A.h without `#include "B.h"` and have `class B` be completely defined, but `class B` also can't use `A::a_struct_t` in B.h without `include "A.h"` and have `class A` be completely defined. I've tried forward declaring `class A` in B.h, but I still can't use `A::a_struct_t` in B.h because `class A` is an incomplete type.

I can move `a_struct_t` to `class B` which works, but it really belongs in `class A`. Also I can friend entire `class B` and not `#include "B.h"` in A.h which also works, but ideally I'd like to just friend `void B::b_func1()` instead of the entire `class B`. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks in advance,

P.S. - I've read about the forward declaration that was the top comment in the other thread. That unfortunately doesn't work in my case, at least I've not been able to apply forward declaration in a way to rid of the `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class xxx'`

Comment: Move `a_struct` and `another_struct` to separate header.

Comment: Read up on pre-declarations, ie. predeclare B before A, and *remove* the include for the definition of B in the source (cpp) of A.

Comment: @Dialecticus of course that's another way to go, but ideally I'd like both structs in the A class, and I'm wondering if there is a way to do it.

Comment: @StarShine if you meant forward declare, I've already tried forward declaring `class B` in A.h and forward declaring `class A` in B.h. Both gives me the compile `error: invalid use of incomplete type xxx`.

Comment: Correct. You have to use the type as a pointer type or reference type. i.e. you can assign the actual instance to the reference  type (later (or dereference it and assign it to the pointer type)